# Algorithm to generate splats from point clouds

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to write a program to generate splats from point clouds from following [this](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Ekashyap08/seminar/report.pdf) paper and [this](http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg/Papers_2007/journal/C89-full.pdf) paper.

The function I have to generate 1 splat is here:

```
def generate_splat(pcd, pcd_tree, point, k, threshold, perc, points, activated):
    [k, idx, _] = pcd_tree.search_knn_vector_3d(point, k) #Find k nearest neighbors indexes to point
    found_points = points[idx] # Create an array from those indexes
    normal = fitPLaneLTSQ(found_points) # Get normal of the best fit plane of those points
    sds = [] # To keep track of all signed distances
    i = 0
    while True:
        h = normal.dot(found_points[0] - found_points[i]) #Calculate signed distance of point to plane
        if abs(h) < threshold and i + 1 < k: #Check if it is below threshold
            sds.append(h)
        else:
            center = found_points[0] + ((max(sds) - min(sds)) / 2) * normal #Center calculation
            radius = np.linalg.norm((found_points[i] - center) - normal.dot(found_points[i] - center) * normal) #Radius calculation
            break
        i += 1
    [k, idx, _] = pcd_tree.search_radius_vector_3d(point, radius * perc)
    np.asarray(pcd.colors)[idx[1:], :] = [0, 1, 1] # Convert all relevant points to blue.
    activated[idx] = True
    return Splat(center, normal, radius, points)
```

and this is its profile:
[image]
Is there any way to optimize this further? My point cloud has over around 10 million points and this function is run around 2,000,000 times. I can't really think of a way to make this concurrent as to generate 1 splat I must know what points are contained in the other splats already generated.

**EDIT**:

I converted the loop from pure python to numpy like this:

```
def generate_splat(pcd, pcd_tree, point, k, threshold, perc, points, activated):
    [k, idx, _] = pcd_tree.search_knn_vector_3d(point, k)
    found_points = points[idx]    
    normal = fitPLaneLTSQ(found_points)
    h = (found_points[0] - found_points).dot(normal)
    f = np.abs(h) < threshold
    v = np.where(f == 0)[0]
    if v.size == 0:
        ind = k - 1
        trueh = h
    else:
        ind = v[0]
        trueh = h[:ind]

    center = found_points[0] + normal * ((np.amax(trueh) - np.amin(trueh)) / 2)
    radius = np.linalg.norm((found_points[ind] - center) - normal.dot(found_points[ind] - center) * normal)

    [k, idx, _] = pcd_tree.search_radius_vector_3d(point, radius * perc)
    np.asarray(pcd.colors)[idx[1:], :] = [0, 1, 1] # Convert all relevant points to blue.
    activated[idx] = True
    return Splat(center, normal, radius, points)
```

and got a huge speedup. Now the profile looks like this and I truly can't any other way to make the code faster.
[image]

Comment: The fact that the statements taking the most time have a similar per hit as a very simple statement like `i += 1` suggests that there probably isn't much you can do to speed up that loop in pure python. Would it be possible to run your code in an alternate implementation like pypy or to put your loop into something like a [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) jitted function?

Comment: Hmm I looked at some other posts and realized my looping could be improved so I made it all in numpy and got a huge speedup.